# How to proper user in-line concatenation?

Tags: php, oop, concatenation

I'm working on the pagination of a website and I got to the point where I need to highlight the number of the page that is on.

I'm having a hard time with semantic at this line bellow, more specifically with what's between **. The whole code is also bellow.

Please note that ** is not part of the code.

Could anyone help to put this line together.

```
    <? $saida .='<li><a'.**if $i == $_GET['page'] echo 'class="active"';**.'href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>'; ?>
```

Here is my whole code

```
<?php

function montaTexto($texto){
    $texto = str_replace("<hr>","<hr />",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("<hr/>","<hr />",$texto);
    $texto = explode('<hr />',$texto);

    $x = 0;
    foreach($texto as $s =>$v){
        $x++;
        $texto[$x] = $v;
    }

    if (!empty($_GET['page'])){
        $saida = $texto[$_GET['page']];
    } else {
        $saida = $texto[1];
    }

    if ($x > 1){
        $saida .= '<div class="pagination bottom">
              <p>-'.strip_tags($categoria['titulo_topo']).'-</p>
              <ul>';              
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++){
              $saida .='<li><a'. if $i == $_GET['page'] echo 'class="active"'; .'href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
        $saida .='</ul>
              <p><a href="?page='.($x).'">&gt;&gt;</a></p>
              </div> ';
    }
    return $saida;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a ternary conditional operator:

```
$saida .='<li><a'. ($i == $_GET['page'] ? ' class="active"' : '') .' href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

**EDIT** fixed a bug :)

Test:

```
$ cat paging.php 
<?php
    $_GET['page'] = '5';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $saida .='<li><a'. ($i == $_GET['page'] ? ' class="active"' : '') .' href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>' . "\n";
    }

    var_dump($saida);
$ php paging.php 
string(345) "<li><a href="?page=0">0</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=4">4</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="?page=5">5</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=6">6</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=7">7</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=8">8</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=9">9</a></li>
"
```

Comment: I couldn't use the inline conditional even after playing a little bit with the code you suggested. It worked  when I passed the result of the conditional to a variable and then doing the concatenation. 

Thanks for the suggestion but I would still got the same result with a regular if. ;)

I appreciate the link though. Good stuff.


    $variable = ($i == $_GET['page'] ? ' class="active"' : '');
    $saida .='<li><a'. $variable .' href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

Comment: There was a little bug in my answer code, now I fixed it. It works for me.